# Convert Epoch which is in UTC to current time zone date

Tags: javascript

I am returning data using JSON in ASp.NET MVC. The date is converted to say

```
\\/Date(1444089473757)\
```

This date i am storing in my DB in UTC.

I am want to convert the date to current datetime object in javascript.

I tried using moment.js and other functions like

```
var date = new Date(parseInt((this.DateAdded).substr(6)));;
date = new Date(parseInt(this.DateAdded.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));


var date = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
date.setUTCSeconds(parseInt(utcSeconds / 1000));
```

All create date in browser time zone and not utc.

What i want is to create a date in UTC so i can offset to browser time zone

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use getTimeZone offset to get the number of minutes of the offset, multiply it by 60 to get the number of seconds, and add or subtract that to the number before passing it to the Date constructor

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

For example

```
var myDate= new Date(myTimestamp + 60 * (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset());
```

...or maybe that should be a 'minus'... but you get the idea

Comment: No this does not work for me. This is considering the myTimestamp which is of UTC as current time zone timestamp

Comment: My timestamp which is 1444133845847 need to be converted based upon current timezone date

Comment: Ok... so why not just use `new Date(1444089473757)` ? This returns a date object corresponding to your UTC timestamp. This date object has plenty of methods to extract the local representation of this point in time